# How to mock es6 class using Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am attempting to mock a class `Mailer` using jest and I can't figure out how to do it. The docs don't give many examples of how this works. The process is the I will have a node event `password-reset` that is fired and when that event is fired, I want to send an email using `Mailer.send(to, subject, body)`. Here is my directory structure:

```
project_root
-- __test__
---- server
------ services
-------- emails
---------- mailer.test.js
-- server
---- services
------ emails
-------- mailer.js
-------- __mocks__
---------- mailer.js
```

Here is my mock file `__mocks__/mailer.js`:

```
const Mailer = jest.genMockFromModule('Mailer');

function send(to, subject, body) {
  return { to, subject, body };
}

module.exports = Mailer;
```

and my `mailer.test.js`

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const Mailer = jest.mock('../../../../server/services/emails/mailer');

test('sends an email when the password-reset event is fired', () => {
  const send = Mailer.send();
  const event = new EventEmitter();
  event.emit('password-reset');
  expect(send).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

and finally my `mailer.js` class:

```
class Mailer {

  constructor() {
    this.mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({
      apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY,
      domain: process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN,
    });
  }

  send(to, subject, body) {
    return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
      this.mailgun.messages().send({
        from: 'Securely App <friendly-robot@securelyapp.com>',
        to,
        subject: subject,
        html: body,
      }, (error, body) => {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }

        return resolve('The email was sent successfully!');
      });
    });
  }

}

module.exports = new Mailer();
```

So, how do I successfully mock and test this class, using Jest? Many thanks for helping!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You don't have to mock your mailer class but the `mailgun-js` module. So mailgun is a function that returns the function `messages` that return the function `send`. So the mock will look like this.

for the happy path

```
const happyPath = () => ({
  messages: () => ({
    send: (args, callback) => callback()
  })
})
```

for the error case

```
const errorCase = () => ({
  messages: () => ({
    send: (args, callback) => callback('someError')
  })
})
```

as you have this 2 cases it make sense to mock the module inside your test. First you have to mock it with a simple spy where we later can set the implementation for our cases and then we have to import the module.

```
jest.mock('mailgun-js', jest.fn())
import mailgun from 'mailgun-js'
import Mailer from '../../../../server/services/emails/mailer'
```

As your module uses promises we have 2 options either return the promise from the test or use `async/await`. I use the later one for more info have a look [here](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html#content).

```
test('test the happy path', async() => {
 //mock the mailgun so it returns our happy path mock
  mailgun.mockImplementation(() => happyPath)
  //we need to use async/awit here to let jest recognize the promise
  const send = await Mailer.send();
  expect(send).toBe('The email was sent successfully!')
});
```

If you would like to test that the mailgun `send` method was called with the correct parameter you need to adapt the mock like this:

```
const send = jest.fn((args, callback) => callback())
const happyPath = () => ({
  messages: () => ({
    send: send
  })
})
```

Now you could check that the first parameter for send was correct:

```
expect(send.mock.calls[0][0]).toMatchSnapshot()
```

Comment: I can't wait to get home and try this out. Thank you so much for the super-great explanation.

Comment: Tried with the same way to mock mailgun-js, but endup with receiving the error `mailgun_js_1.default is not a function`

Answer (score 17):

Just for Googlers and future visitors, here's how I've setup jest mocking for ES6 classes.
I also have a [working example at github](https://github.com/justusromijn/jest-es6-mocking), with babel-jest for transpiling the ES module syntax so that jest can mock them properly.

**__mocks__/MockedClass.js**

```
const stub = {
  someMethod: jest.fn(),
  someAttribute: true
}

module.exports = () => stub;
```

Your code can call this with new, and in your tests you can call the function and overwrite any default implementation.

**example.spec.js**

```
const mockedClass = require("path/to/MockedClass")(); 
const AnotherClass = require("path/to/AnotherClass");
let anotherClass;

jest.mock("path/to/MockedClass");

describe("AnotherClass", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockedClass.someMethod.mockImplementation(() => {
      return { "foo": "bar" };
    });

    anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
  });

  describe("on init", () => {
    beforeEach(() => { 
      anotherClass.init(); 
    });

    it("uses a mock", () => {
      expect(mockedClass.someMethod.toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(anotherClass.settings)
        .toEqual(expect.objectContaining({ "foo": "bar" }));
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Not working for me. `mockedClass.someMethod` is `undefined`. Using jest 21.2.1.

Comment: what is "path/to/YourClass"? the only clases that appear in the code are: mockedClass and AnotherClass. I guess it should be "path/to/MockedClass" instead, am I right?

Comment: @PacketTracer you are correct! I've updated the code example.

Comment: @JustusRomijn, awesome - I have been searching for a solution for this for quite some time, but returning a function that always returns the same instance is pretty smart. Thanks!

Comment: @JustusRomijn, how can you call `new` on an arrow function? I get error 'mockedClass is not a constructor' when AnotherClass calls `new mockedClass()`.

Comment: Hmm well for me it works, but maybe that is because the arrow function is assigned to the exports property of the module, so it acts as a method. In that case it inherits some properties and it might become "new"-able because of this. I will clarify the code example a bit to make sure all pieces are connected properly.

Comment: I've updated my answer to point to a working example, a github repo.

Comment: babel-preset-env, which your repo is using, converts the code to ES5, which doesn't have arrow functions or classes. So it looks like this answer works for those transpiling to ES5, but not for native ES6 code. I'm working on updating the Jest docs for mocking ES6 classes and wanted to be sure I understood what was happening here. Thanks for putting that repo up!

Comment: @stone I don't think mocking works for non-transpiled imports though. Because then you don't have a hook to replace the returned code with something else. By transpiling the imports, it can use some custom code to not just return the original file, but do some magic to return something else instead.

Comment: @JustusRomijn My comment is about transpiling **to ES5**. That is not related to jest's module system, which in any case is not a transpiler.