# ES6 class jest mocking

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have an ES6 class which I need to mock it's methods. Following the documentation i made a manual mock of this, and got the constructor to both be called and asserted.

My function that consumes this class is just a basic function that runs one of the class methods.

**test.js**

```
const mockConnect = jest.fn();
const mockAccess = jest.fn();
jest.mock('../../src/connection');
const connection = require('../../src/connection').default;

connection.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    connect: mockConnect,
    access: mockAccess.mockReturnValue(true),
  };
});

caller_function(); 
expect(connection).toHaveBeenCalled(); // works properly as the constructor is called
expect(connection).toHaveBeenCalledWith('something'); // works
expect(mockAccess).toHaveBeenCalled(); // says it was not called when it should have
```

**caller_function.js**

```
import connection from 'connection';
const conn = new connection('something');

export function caller_function() {
  conn.access(); // returns undefined when mock says it should return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're using `mockImplementation()` instead of a manual mock or the factory parameter to `jest.mock()`, *and* your mocked object is being created during the module loading process, since the constructor call is not inside of any function. What's happening is:

1. The call to `jest.mock('../../src/connection')` runs and sets `connection` to be an automatic mock.
2. The `conn` object is created using the automatic mock. Therefore its `access` method returns undefined.
3. The call to `mockImplementation()` happens, changing the `connection` mock. However, since the `conn` object has already been created, it doesn't get the custom implementation.

Moving the constructor call into `caller_function` is one way to fix it:

```
export function caller_function() {
  const conn = new connection('something');
  conn.access();
}
```

You could also use the factory parameter to `jest.mock()`, specifying the implementation there, instead of calling `mockImplementation()`. That way you won't have to change your implementation code:

```
const mockConnect = jest.fn();
const mockAccess = jest.fn();
import connection from '../../src/connection';
jest.mock('./so-import', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      connect: mockConnect,
      access: mockAccess.mockReturnValue(true)
    };
  });
});

...
```

BTW the convention for ES6 class names is to begin with an uppercase letter. I was temporarily confused by the lowercase name `connection`.

Comment: Sorry, in my actual work it is using a Capital letter, in my rush to retype some of the code out i forgot to capitalize it

Comment: Got it working, thanks a bunch! Oddly i had the mock running in jest.mock but since it is an es6 class i need to do a mockimplementation in my jest.mock and that makes it work

Comment: Good point. I hadn't tested that code. Updated, should work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing `connection.mockClear();` before you write a mockImplementation for the methods?
Also please refer to this https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks

Comment: I did a jest.resetModules(); This is also the first and only time i am using `connection` mock