# How to mock an asynchronous function call in another class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jestjs

I have the following (simplified) React component.

```
class SalesView extends Component<{}, State> {
  state: State = {
    salesData: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchSalesData();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.salesData) {
      return <SalesChart salesData={this.state.salesData} />;
    } else {
      return <p>Loading</p>;
    }
  }

  async fetchSalesData() {
    let data = await new SalesService().fetchSalesData();
    this.setState({ salesData: data });
  }
}
```

When mounting, I fetch data from an API, which I have abstracted away in a class called `SalesService`. This class I want to mock, and for the method `fetchSalesData` I want to specify the return data (in a promise).

This is more or less how I want my test case to look like:

- predefine test data
- import SalesView
- mock SalesService
- setup mockSalesService to return a promise that returns the predefined test data when resolved
- create the component
- await
- check snapshot

Testing the looks of SalesChart is not part of this question, I hope to solve that using Enzyme. I have been trying dozens of things to mock this asynchronous call, but I cannot seem to get this mocked properly. I have found the following examples of Jest mocking online, but they do not seem to cover this basic usage.

- [Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/testing-react-components-with-jest-and-enzyme-41d592c174f): Does not use asychronous calls
- [Wehkamp tech blog](https://medium.com/wehkamp-techblog/unit-testing-your-react-application-with-jest-and-enzyme-81c5545cee45): Does not use asynchronous calls
- [Agatha Krzywda](https://medium.com/@aghh1504/6-testing-react-components-using-jest-and-enzyme-b85db96fa1e3): Does not use asynchronous calls
- [GitConnected](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/testing-asynchronous-and-synchronous-react-components-with-jest-and-enzyme-a979ab425aa1): Does not use a class with a function to mock
- [Jest tutorial An Async Example](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html): Does not use a class with a function to mock
- [Jest tutorial Testing Asynchronous Code](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html): Does not use a class with a function to mock
- [SO question 43749845](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749845/how-to-mock-es6-class-using-jest): I can't connect the mock to the real implementation in this way
- [42638889](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638889/jest-mock-async-calls-inside-react-component): Is using dependency injection, I am not
- [46718663](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718663/how-do-test-async-components-with-jest): Is not showing how the actual mock Class is implemented

My questions are:

- How should the mock class look like?
- Where should I place this mock class?
- How should I import this mock class?
- How do I tell that this mock class replaces the real class?
- How do set up the mock implementation of a specific function of the mock class?
- How do I wait in the test case for the promise to be resolved?

One example that I have that does not work is given below. The test runner crashes with the error `throw err;` and the last line in the stack trace is `at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)`

```
# __tests__/SalesView-test.js
import React from 'react';
import SalesView from '../SalesView';

jest.mock('../SalesService');
const salesServiceMock = require('../SalesService').default;

const weekTestData = [];

test('SalesView shows chart after SalesService returns data', async () => {
  salesServiceMock.fetchSalesData.mockImplementation(() => {
    console.log('Mock is called');
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      process.nextTick(() => resolve(weekTestData));
    });
  });

  const wrapper = await shallow(<SalesView/>);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Depending on how you're making the XHR calls, you might want to look at [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) or [axios-mock-adapter](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter).

Comment: Thanks! That is interesting to mock actual HTTP calls, but I am looking for a way to mock my own classes with asynchronous functionality. That they make an HTTP request is a special case.

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes, when a test is hard to write, it is trying to tell us that we have a design problem.

I think a small refactor could make things a lot easier - make `SalesService` a collaborator instead of an internal.

By that I mean, instead of calling `new SalesService()` inside your component, accept the sales service as a prop by the calling code. If you do that, then the calling code can also be your test, in which case all you need to do is mock the `SalesService` itself, and return whatever you want (using sinon or any other mocking library, or even just creating a hand rolled stub).

Answer (score 6):

You could potentially abstract the `new` keyword away using a `SalesService.create()` method, then use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) to mock the implementation.

```
import SalesService from '../SalesService ';

test('SalesView shows chart after SalesService returns data', async () => {

    const mockSalesService = {
        fetchSalesData: jest.fn(() => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                process.nextTick(() => resolve(weekTestData));
            });
        })
    };

    const spy = jest.spyOn(SalesService, 'create').mockImplementation(() => mockSalesService);

    const wrapper = await shallow(<SalesView />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockSalesService.fetchSalesData).toHaveBeenCalled();

    spy.mockReset();
    spy.mockRestore();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One "ugly" way I've used in the past is to do a sort of poor-man's dependency injection.

It's based on the fact that you might not really want to go about instantiating `SalesService` every time you need it, but rather you want to hold a single instance per application, which everybody uses. In my case, `SalesService` required some initial configuration which I didn't want to repeat every time.[1]

So what I did was have a `services.ts` file which looks like this:

```
/// In services.ts
let salesService: SalesService|null = null;
export function setSalesService(s: SalesService) {
    salesService = s;
}
export function getSalesService() {
    if(salesService == null) throw new Error('Bad stuff');
    return salesService;
}
```

Then, in my application's `index.tsx` or some similar place I'd have:

```
/// In index.tsx
// initialize stuff
const salesService = new SalesService(/* initialization parameters */)
services.setSalesService(salesService);
// other initialization, including calls to React.render etc.
```

In the components you can then just use `getSalesService` to get a reference to the one `SalesService` instance per application.

When it comes time to test, you just need to do some setup in your `mocha` (or whatever) `before` or `beforeEach` handlers to call `setSalesService` with a mock object.

Now, ideally, you'd want to pass in `SalesService` as a prop to your component, because it *is* an input to it, and by using `getSalesService` you're hiding this dependency and possibly causing you grief down the road. But if you need it in a very nested component, or if you're using a router or somesuch, it's becomes quite unwieldy to pass it as a prop.

You might also get away with using something like [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), to keep everything inside React as it were.

The "ideal" solution for this would be something like dependency injection, but that's not an option with React AFAIK.

---

[1] It can also help in providing a single point for serializing remote-service calls, which might be needed at some point.