# Jest `mock.calls` empty with mocked typescript class

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I've got a typescript class `EntityConfigurationMapper`, with a `map` method. I'm mocking it in my Jest tests like this:

```
const mock = jest.fn<EntityConfigurationMapper>()
      .mockImplementation(() => ({
        map: (conf): Entity => {
          return {...};
        }
      }));
const instance = new entityConfigurationMapperMock();
```

Then it gets used etc.

I want to check the calls, [which should be like](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockcalls) `mock.calls[0][0]` etc. However, the `mock.calls` is an empty array.

I've put a console in the mocked `map` method, and it outputs as expected, so the mock is calling the mocked implementation, just not recording it the `calls` array.

Any idea why `calls` would be empty?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, worked it out with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749845/how-to-mock-es6-class-using-jest). You have to use jest.fn to mock the function calls as well as the class:

```
const map = jest.fn((conf, ids): Entity  => {
  return {...};
})

const mock = jest.fn<EntityConfigurationMapper>()
    .mockImplementation(() => ({
      map
    }));
const instance = new entityConfigurationMapperMock();
```

You can then investigate the calls on `map`:

```
map.mock.calls
```